# "grunt install" returns error on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, ubuntu-14.04

I get the following error when I try to run "grunt install" on a Ubuntu 14.04 box that has the latest nodejs installed from NodeSource.

> jit-grunt: Plugin for the "install" task not found. If you have
>   installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping. See
>   https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings
>
> Warning: Task "install" failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Here is the part of Gruntfile.js related to jit-grunt:

```
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    injector: 'grunt-asset-injector',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control'
  });
```

Can someone point to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `grunt install` task? Can you please paste your `package.json` file here so we may see your dependencies?

The reason `jit-grunt` is outputting that error is because it cannot find a node module folder named `grunt-contrib-install`, `grunt-install`, or `install`, with a `tasks/` folder with JS files that register a Grunt task named `install`.

Do you mean either of these packages? If so, you have to call them via their registered task names:
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-npm-install – `grunt npm-install`
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-auto-install – `grunt auto_install`

For the `grunt-auto-install` package, you will need to add it to `jit-grunt`'s static mappings, like you have with `grunt-express-server` and others.

---

If it's not the above, apart from "maybe you mistyped?", the only other answer I can offer is similar to the assumption @waqas-ahmed made: that you mean to install `dependencies` and `devDependencies` from your `package.json` file, and that perhaps you mean to call `npm install`, not `grunt install`.

Comment: Here follows the link to package.json.        https://gist.github.com/digiwise/4d13cc807198ef8b3498

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything in there that would provide a grunt task named `install`. I think you mistyped when you ran `grunt install`. The solution is to not run `grunt install` =)

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
 1) npm install -g grunt-cli
```

This will put the grunt command in your system path, allowing it to be run from any directory.

Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner! The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

```
 2) npm install grunt --save-dev
```

The easiest way to add Grunt and gruntplugins to an existing package.json is with the command npm install  --save-dev. Not only will this install  locally, but it will automatically be added to the devDependencies section, using a tilde version range.

for further assistance follow this link

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: The issue does not seem to be related to the grunt-cli installation. Re-installing the grunt-cli and grunt did not solve the problem. This problem is more likely to be related to how Ubuntu deals with access rights.